# My collection view is nil when implicit unwrapping?

Tags: swift, delegates, collectionview

I use a `UITabBarController` to manage the large middle button on the `UITabBar`. Here is a part of it.

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate, ContentChangedDelegate { 
         override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           setupMiddleButton()
         }

func setupMiddleButton() {
    
    let tabBarHeight = tabBar.frame.size.height
    
   
    let menuButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tabBarHeight*1.5, height: tabBarHeight*1.5))
    var menuButtonFrame = menuButton.frame
    
    menuButtonFrame.origin.y = view.bounds.height - menuButtonFrame.height/2 - tabBarHeight - 8

    menuButtonFrame.origin.x = view.bounds.width/2 - menuButtonFrame.size.width/2
    menuButton.frame = menuButtonFrame
    
    menuButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    menuButton.layer.cornerRadius = menuButtonFrame.height/2
    view.addSubview(menuButton)
    
    let largeConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(scale: .large)
    let addIcon = UIImage(systemName: "plus", withConfiguration: largeConfiguration)
    menuButton.setImage((addIcon), for: .normal)
    
    menuButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(menuButtonAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@objc private func menuButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    AddViewController.delegate = self
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "addEventSegue", sender: self)
}
```

}
and I conform another class LifeViewController(I used the class the specify the collecitonView and searchbar and other items in it) to tabBarController but the lifeCollectionView is always nil when implicitly unwrap, Could any one help me, Thank you so much!

```
class LifeViewController: TabBarController {

let realm = try! Realm()
var reminders : Results<Memorandum>!

let tabBarView = TabBarController()

@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet var lifeCollectionView: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    self.fetchData()
    lifeCollectionView.delegate = self
    lifeCollectionView.dataSource = self
   
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.fetchData()
}

 override func reloadCollection() {
     if let life = self.lifeCollectionView {
               life.reloadData()
           } else {
               print("life found nil")
           }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "editing", sender: self)
    
}


func fetchData() {
    
    reminders = realm.objects(Memorandum.self)

}
```

}

```
//MARK: - CollectionView


extension LifeViewController {
    
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
         return CGSize(width: lifeCollectionView.frame.width/2.1, height: lifeCollectionView.frame.width/2.1)
     }
     

     
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         return reminders.count
     }
     
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
         
         let reminder = reminders[indexPath.item]
         
         let lifeCell = lifeCollectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "lifeCell", for: indexPath) as! ReminderCell
         
         lifeCell.configureCell(date: reminder.dateReminder, importance: UIColor(hex: reminder.color)!, name: reminder.title, depict: reminder.depiction)
             
         lifeCell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
         
         return lifeCell
         
     }
    
    
}
```

But when I change back to conform the `LifeViewController` to `UIViewController`, and other collection view protocols the `IBOutlet`, `delegate` and `dataSource` work again? Why is that?

Comment: How you show `LifeViewController` ?

Comment: I think your collection view name is `lifeCollectionView`  and you have to use that name `lifeCollectionView.delegate = self lifeCollectionView.dataSource = self` and you have to add `class LifeViewController: TabBarController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {` for collection methods

Comment: Sorry, that's a mistake.  But I have extension on that TabBarController conforming those collectionDelegates and I used lifeCollectionView in my code. @KishanBhatiya

Comment: How you present or show `LifeViewController`, can you provide code for that?

Comment: I've put the whole LifeViewController on it.

Comment: Why are you conforming LifeViewController as TabBarController. You should add LifeViewController as a first view controller in tab bar controller.

Comment: lifeCollectionView check its connection in Storyboard